# IIS monitoring tool

Tags: iis

I have a web site that seems to become slow at random times. Is there some logging tool that I can run to see when and why my asp.net seems to slow down? One of the pages has a button which does a post back and updates a ajax grid after updating the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IIS log analyzer

http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1864